# Why is a http request made when I login via https with Vaadin 23 and SpringBoot 2.7

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

i have a strange behaviour during log in to a Vaadin application that is running with spring boot.
See attached picture. The call to the root page is suddenly made with the wrong protocol (http) instead of https. This page does nothing but forward to another view.

```
@RolesAllowed({ "ADMINISTRATOR" })
@Route(value = "", layout = MainLayout.class)
public class StartView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver {

@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    event.forwardTo(ServiceView.class);
}
```

}

[image: Network calls during login]

I have configured a nginx server on another machine to listen to the server address and forward the requests to the port the spring-boot application is running on.
[image: NginxProxy config]

Without the proxy config with directly pointing to the address and the port with http everything works as expected. But since there are passwords transferred we need a secure connection.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking
a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: My guess, but maybe hard to tell due to the blurring: you have push enabled in the application - but your nginx config does not contain a config for the websocket (also hard to tell, because it's not searchable); for the request to `/`, can you rule out, that there is no reference inside your "login.html" to something insecure?

Comment: Yes you are right push is enabled, so I have to add the proper configuration how wss:// should be handled. Unfortunetly I only have that image and no direct access to the config. Maybe the issue is related and it is gone if I fix the wss issue. I had a look into the rendered LoginView page but there is nothing referring to http. just the form and the login action.